# Numpy create block matrices from object type numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to create block matrices with numpy with this shape

[image]

Where each entry is a 4x4 matrix.

As an example lets fill all the entries with 4x4 zero matrices.

```
N = 9
sizeOfBlock = 4
A = np.zeros((N, N), dtype =object)

for i in np.arange(N):
    for j in np.arange(N):
        A[i,j] = np.zeros((sizeOfBlock,sizeOfBlock))
```

This will create the matrix with the correct shape.
Now I would like to convert it from a 9x9 matrix of object to a 36x36 matrix will all the entries.

Any way to do this?

Best Regards

Comment: Why can't you create a 4d array `9 x 9 x 4 x 4` from the beginning, and then reshape into `36 x 36`? `A = np.zeros(9,9,4,4); A = A.reshape((36, 36))`

Comment: For 1d object dtype arrays, `concatenate` or one of the `stack` functions can be used to combine the objects, provided they have the right shapes.  `concatenate` treats the 1d object array as a sequence, a list.  `np.block` can handle nested lists, basically by recursively combining the sublists and outer list.

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich's suggestion is a good one, but the simple reshape won't work--you'll need to interchange the middle axes first, e.g `A = np.zeros(9,9,4,4);  A = np.swapaxes(A, 1, 2).reshape((36, 36))`.

Comment: What about `A = np.bmat(A.tolist())` ?

Comment: @ManuelOliveira, `bmat` returns a `np.matrix` object.

Comment: So it would be better to have `A = np.block(A.tolist())`?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of object dtype array has few, if any, advantages over a list of lists.

`block` can make an array from nested lists of arrays:

```
In [294]: A=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2); Z=np.zeros((2,2),int)
In [295]: np.block([[A,Z],[Z,A]])
Out[295]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 3]])
```

An object dtype array:

```
In [296]: O = np.empty((2,2),object)
In [298]: O[0,0]=O[1,1]=A
In [300]: O[0,1]=O[1,0]=Z
In [301]: O
Out[301]: 
array([[array([[0, 1],
               [2, 3]]), array([[0, 0],
                                [0, 0]])],
       [array([[0, 0],
               [0, 0]]), array([[0, 1],

                                [2, 3]])]], dtype=object)
```

`block` doesn't do anything useful with that:

```
In [302]: np.block(O)
Out[302]: 
array([[array([[0, 1],
               [2, 3]]), array([[0, 0],
                                [0, 0]])],
       [array([[0, 0],
               [0, 0]]), array([[0, 1],
                                [2, 3]])]], dtype=object)
```

However if we turn into a list of lists as in [295]

```
In [303]: np.block(O.tolist())
Out[303]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 3]])
```

The current code of `block` is obscured with the dispatching layer, but when I looked at it in the past, it was using a recursive `hstack` and `vstack`

```
In [307]: np.vstack((np.hstack(O[0]),np.hstack(O[1])))
Out[307]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 3]])
```

`concatenate` and family can handle 1d object dtype arrays, treating them as a sequence, or list, of arrays.  They can't work directly with 2d arrays.

Comments suggest working with a 4d array:

```
In [308]: arr = np.array([[A,Z],[Z,A]])
In [309]: arr
Out[309]: 
array([[[[0, 1],
         [2, 3]],

        [[0, 0],
         [0, 0]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [0, 0]],

        [[0, 1],
         [2, 3]]]])
```

simple reshape doesn't not preserve the block layout:

```
In [310]: arr.reshape(4,4)
Out[310]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

but an axis swap will:

```
In [311]: arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[311]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 3]])
```

For some layouts, Kronecker product does the job

```
In [315]: np.kron(np.eye(2).astype(int),A)
Out[315]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 3]])
```